# The isrealites were being called Judah and later Jew?

Tags: hebrew, history

Why and when were the isrealites being called Judah and later Jew?

Comment: Hi rsai, welcome to the site! Could you clarify your question and/or what passages you are referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Originally "Israel" referred to all the descendants of Jacob (who was renamed Israel), divided into 12 tribes each named after one of his 12 sons.
King Saul, and then King David and then his son King Solomon ruled all of Israel from Jerusalem.
This is the period (Around 1000 BCE) when the Great Temple was built, and Israel became a rich and powerful nation.

But later kings didn't follow God's way and the kingdom broke into two parts.
The northern part retained the name "Israel" as the name was inherited by the tribe of Joseph.
The smaller southern part was comprised of the tribe of Judah and the remnant of Benjamin, and ruled from Jerusalem.
A short form for people from the Kingdom of Judah was "Jew".

The first time the word "Jew" is used in the Bible is 2 Kings 16:6:

> In the seventeenth year of Pekah the son of Remaliah Ahaz the son of Jotham *king of Judah* began to reign.
> …
> Then Rezin king of Syria and Pekah son of Remaliah *king of Israel* came up to Jerusalem to war: and they besieged Ahaz, but could not overcome him.
> At that time Rezin king of Syria recovered Elath to Syria, and drave the *Jews* from Elath: and the Syrians came to Elath, and dwelt there unto this day.
> — 1 Kings 16:1–6

Note that Syria and *Israel* are allied in a war *against* the *Jews*.

The Jews were eventually taken into captivity in Babylon, but later returned to the land of Judah and Jerusalem.
It is their descendants that are known as Jews to this day.

The Israelites were later taken into captivity in Assyria (nothing to do with Syria), and never returned.
What happened to these "ten lost tribes" is another story, mostly missing from conventional history.